# How can I get browser URL via API of a Google Spreadsheet from its id?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm importing a csv file to Google spreadsheet via API,
I have a DocumentListEntry object:

```
DocumentList docs = new DocumentList("test");

docs.login(adminEmail, adminPassword);
DocumentListEntry newDocs=docs.uploadFile(uploadfilepath, filename);
```

I can retrieve its id doing newDocs.getDocId() but how I can find the URL to be used as a link in browser to open the document?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Drive SDK API "files/get" to get web url by fileid. The API document is here:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get

From the result json file, there is a "alternateLink" which is right what you wanted.